# Probability question: average number of objects per class when drawing from a pool of N objects belonging to M classes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This question is a bit convoluted so I will try to frame it as simply as possible.

Suppose that I have a bag containing shapes ($s$) of different colors ($c$). For instance, I have red squares, red circles, red triangles; blue squares, blue stars; yellow triangles and yellow stars. There are $C$ colors in total, and there are $S_c$ shape types of color $c$. In the example above, $C=3$ (red, blue and yellow); $S_{\mathrm{red}} = 3$ (squares, circles and triangles); $S_{\mathrm{blue}} = 2$ (squares and stars); $S_{\mathrm{yellow}} = 2$ (triangles and stars).

There are multiple copies of each object that are not necessarily the same, e.g. I can have 15 red circles, 6 red squares, 25 yellow triangles and so on. Let us call $N_{c,s}$ to the number of copies of the shape $s$ in color $c$.

I draw $n$ objects from the bag with replacement. The question is, what is the average number of shape types per color in the sample, *not counting the colors that were not sampled*? For instance, if my sample of size $n=7$ consisted of 3 red circles, 2 red squares and 2 blue stars, I would have:

- 2 types of shapes in red
- 1 type of shape in blue

And therefore the average number of shapes per color drawn would be $(2 + 1)/2 = 1.5$. Since my sample contains no yellow objects, these are excluded from the average. Note that this is independent of how many objects of each combination of color + shape were drawn, for instance if I had drawn 1 red circle, 5 red squares and 1 blue star the answer would still be the same since I would still have 2 types of red shapes and 1 type of blue shape.

If I call $p_c$ to the probability that the color $c$ is sampled at least once, then:

$$ p_c \left( n \right) = 1 - \left(1-\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{S_c} N_{c,j}}{\sum_{i=1}^{C} \sum_{j=1}^{S_i} N_{i,j}}\right)^n $$

Which is just one minus the probability that the color $c$ is not sampled in any of the $n$ independent draws. I'm guessing the way to go here would be to calculate the probability that $m$ shape types of color $c$ are sampled conditional to the color $c$ being sampled at all. But I honestly don't know how to tackle this.

Any help is much appreciated. I hope my question is not too obscure $-$it's my first time posting here so I apologize if I haven't been clear enough. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks horrendous to try to provide an exact general expression and you might do better to use simulation in specific cases.

Comment: @Henry that's fair. In the end I am interested in understanding under what circumstances the average number of shape types per color increases with n, so I wanted to check if there would be some relatively straightforward way to get an analytical expression. But I may have been overly optimistic indeed... thanks for your reply!